# How to parse a text file with alternating lines of names and lists of integers?

Tags: c#, arrays, file

I need to read a file and put that data inside to different arrays.

My .txt file looks like:

```
w1;
1 2 3
w2;
3 4 5
w3;
4 5 6
```

I tried something like the following:

```
int[] w1 = new int [3];
int[] w2 = new int [3];
int[] w3 = new int [3];

string v = "w1:|w2:|w3:";
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\\Data.txt"))
{
   string[] parts = Regex.Split(line, v);
```

I got that string but I have no idea how to cut every element of  it to arrays showed above.

Comment: @Thaun_ What? That wouldn't help at all, the OP is already using `ReadAllLines`

Comment: And *then* what are you going to do with those arrays? There may be a better overall solution to the underlying problem you're solving.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than parsing the file and putting the arrays into three hardcoded variables corresponding to hardcoded names `w1`, `w2` and `w3`, I would remove the hardcoding and parse the file into a `Dictionary<string, int[]>` like so:

```
public static class DataFileExtensions
{
    public static Dictionary<string, int[]> ParseDataFile(string fileName)
    {
        var separators = new [] { ' ' };
        var query = from pair in File.ReadLines(fileName).Chunk(2)
                    let key = pair[0].TrimEnd(';')
                    let value = (pair.Count < 2 ? "" : pair[1]).Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => int.Parse(s, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)).ToArray()
                    select new { key, value };
        return query.ToDictionary(p => p.key, p => p.value);
    }
}

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    // Adapted from the answer to "Split List into Sublists with LINQ" by casperOne
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq/
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/419058
    // https://stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone
    public static IEnumerable<List<T>> Chunk<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int groupSize)
    {
        // The list to return.
        List<T> list = new List<T>(groupSize);

        // Cycle through all of the items.
        foreach (T item in enumerable)
        {
            // Add the item.
            list.Add(item);

            // If the list has the number of elements, return that.
            if (list.Count == groupSize)
            {
                // Return the list.
                yield return list;

                // Set the list to a new list.
                list = new List<T>(groupSize);
            }
        }

        // Return the remainder if there is any,
        if (list.Count != 0)
        {
            // Return the list.
            yield return list;
        }
    }
}
```

And you would use it as follows:

```
var dictionary = DataFileExtensions.ParseDataFile(fileName);

Console.WriteLine("Result of parsing {0}, encountered {1} data arrays:", fileName, dictionary.Count);
foreach (var pair in dictionary)
{
    var name = pair.Key;
    var data = pair.Value;

    Console.WriteLine("  Data row name = {0}, values = [{1}]", name, string.Join(",", data));
}
```

Which outputs:

```
Result of parsing Question49341548.txt, encountered 3 data arrays:
  Data row name = w1, values = [1,2,3]
  Data row name = w2, values = [3,4,5]
  Data row name = w3, values = [4,5,6]
```

Notes:

- I parse the integer values using [`NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.invariantinfo.aspx) to ensure consistency of parsing in all locales.
- I break the lines of the file into chunks of two by using a lightly modified version of the method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/419058) to *[Split List into Sublists with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419019/split-list-into-sublists-with-linq/)* by [casperOne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50776/casperone).
- After breaking the file into chunks of pairs of lines, I trim the `;` from the first line in each pair and use that as the dictionary key.  The second line in each pair gets parsed into an array of integer values.
- If the names `w1`, `w2` and so on are not unique, you could deserialize instead into a [`Lookup<string, int []>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) by replacing [`ToDictionary()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548657.aspx) with [`ToLookup()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549211.aspx).
- Rather than loading the entire file into memory upfront using [`File.ReadAllLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx), I enumerate though it sequentially using [`File.ReadLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx).  This should reduce memory usage without any additional complexity.

Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YPg4kC).

Answer (score 2):

Your RegEx doesn't actually do anything, you already have an array with each line separated. What you want to do is just ignore the lines that aren't data:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\\Data.txt");
for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i += 2) // i.e indexes 1, 3 and 5
{
    string[] numbers = lines[i].Split(' ');
}
```

Or, you could just assign given that you know the order:

```
w1 = lines[1].Split(' ');
w2 = lines[3].Split(' ');
w3 = lines[5].Split(' ');
```